# MySQL making a relationship table for different objects

Tags: mysql, database

So, I'm in a dilema.

Wich is the best approach to solve this problem:

I deal with dozens of diferent tables, each one representing a different entity and having at least one unique primary key. (unique in the context of the table itself, that means that it's not guaranteed that one unique value in one table doesn't exists in another)

My mission is to create an intermediate table(s) where I establish the relationship of one 'object' in a table with another. (Something similar to a parent/child relationship).

Some of these tables may have hundreds or thousands rows but the main one may be something around one million.

In most of the cases the relation between two 'objects' is a one-to-one. But there's also some special cases where one object may be linked to two or more objects.

So I come up with two different approaches:

**Table1)** Create a table where we know that there's a single *child/parent(s)* relationship

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| Child | ParentIDa | ParentIDb | ... | ParentIDn |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

**Table 2)** Create a table to represent the relation of *children/parents*:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| CHILD | Typeofchild | PARENT | TypeofParent |
-----------------------------------------------
```

These tables are exclusive. Relations stored in one table maybe not exists on the other. In other words, for the relations of objects of *TypeA* with *TypeN* may be arbitrarily stored in one of these two tables. And the decision of search in one of the two tables should be then hardcoded.

I would prefer to use the second option **only**. So all data is in a single table, but that way I'll end up with a 50 million+ table, wich may cause some performance trouble.

So, by using the first table I may be able to store data more efficiently.

Given your expirience, Am I in the right path? Wich sollution may be the more appropriate to store, maintain with good performance?

**Note**: In table 2 the "*Typeof*" is necessary to preserve the IDs identity.

Thx,

FKK03D057

Comment: You may be able to store information more efficiently, but not with SQL, which uses a horizontal storage manager, so go with option 2 (or variant thereof), or something other than SQL

Comment: Well I keep on researching and found something similiar on [these question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773860/many-to-many-hierarchy-with-multiple-parents-php-mysql) wich leads to [Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAG)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22824/A-Model-to-Represent-Directed-Acyclic-Graphs-DAG-o)